# Find the average array behavior between 2 or multiple arrays

Tags: probability-distributions, covariance, correlation

this is my first post here. I'd like to know how to calculate the average array between 2 or more arrays. say i have a=[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0] and b=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0].

Graph as a time series: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLd0y.jpg]

What i need its an array ***c*** with the same number of elements of arrays ***a*** and ***b***. Array ***c*** should represent the average trend of ***a*** and ***b***. I do NOT refer to the common average (mean) of arrays' elements (value1+value2)/2, but an average of the distribution of the elements.

This is what i want:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQKLg.png]

hope you can help me :)

Comment: What justification do you have for the second yellow peak?

Comment: @Henry if I'm correct second yellow peak should represent the average behavior between the 2 arrays i took as input. the yellow trapezoid shows an average between arrays' elements but does not reflect how the array behave, since both have a peek in the final part.